# Kafka tutorial: java.lang.Object cannot be resolved

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm trying to follow https://kafka.apache.org/25/documentation/streams/tutorial

But it failed compilation with a bunch of errors. This is the first one:

```
The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

I removed all source files and put in a barebone Pipe.java with the following content:

```java
package myapps;
 
public class Pipe {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
 
    }
}
```

And it's still not compiling:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project streams.examples: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /home/fatdragon/Play/kafka/streaming/streams.examples/src/main/java/myapps/Pipe.java:[1] 
[ERROR]         package myapps;
[ERROR]         ^
[ERROR] The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
[ERROR] /home/fatdragon/Play/kafka/streaming/streams.examples/src/main/java/myapps/Pipe.java:[3] 
[ERROR]         public class Pipe {
[ERROR]                      ^^^^
[ERROR] Implicit super constructor Object() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor
[ERROR] /home/fatdragon/Play/kafka/streaming/streams.examples/src/main/java/myapps/Pipe.java:[5] 
[ERROR]         public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
[ERROR]                                 ^^^^^^
[ERROR] String cannot be resolved to a type
[ERROR] /home/fatdragon/Play/kafka/streaming/streams.examples/src/main/java/myapps/Pipe.java:[5] 
[ERROR]         public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
[ERROR]                                                       ^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] Exception cannot be resolved to a type
[ERROR] 4 problems (4 errors)
```

I'm running from a Debian Linux image with this version:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_242-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)
```

Comment: The pom file has a dependency to org.eclipse.tycho / tycho-compiler-jdt / 1.7.0. It works after I commented that out.

Comment: I also had to remove the plugin itself which defined jdt.

Answer (score 0):

There is no runtime library in your classpath.
Check your settings.

Comment: How does that happen?

Comment: probable causes depend on inquirer actions that we don't aware of

Comment: The pom file has a dependency to org.eclipse.tycho / tycho-compiler-jdt / 1.7.0.  It works after I commented that out.